# How can I connect a LAN/IP camera to a specific PC for usage as conference station?

Tags: conferencing, network-camera

In our office meeting room, there is a LAN/IP Camera installed on the wall - with a static IP.

I have installed a PC in that meeting room, and I want to use that camera as a conference camera.

Both Camera and PC are connected to our 48 Gbit switch.

Even just using it with skype (or other video chat tool) and local microphone.

- Is it possible?

  - It's a FOSCAM 18918 (Black) camera (tried to avoid branding)
  - I have all the CD's and manuals that come with the box.
  - neither mention usage with skype or other tools
  - NO USB - Just LAN and wireless

Comment: What model is the LAN/IP Camera ? Can't you connect your PC and LAN/IP Camera with Ethernet cable so you can set the camera to connect to your PC? Actually you should have also got a Installation CD with the camera. I guess you don't have all these things, so maybe if you put the static IP of the camera in your browser you will access the Camera settings. Try it our.

Comment: What model FOSCAM?  Does it have USB capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution: [IP Camera Adapter](http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/)

It should fulfill your needs, looks to be client dependent.